# oracle driver problems in WAS cluster env

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, websphere

I', using ojdbc14.jar to connect to Oracle 10g DB. 
While working on single machine i have to problem to connect to DB,
but in cluster i got this exception:

> J2CA0036E: An exception occurred while
>   invoking method
>   setDataSourceProperties on
>   com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl
>   used by resource jdbc/OracleDSBSCS :
>   com.ibm.ws.exception.WsException:
>   DSRA0023E: The DataSource
>   implementation class
>   "oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource"
>   could not be found.

The driver is on file system of DeploymentManager and JVM variable points to it,
but it looks like other nodes cannot see driver.

I tried to put driver on same place in their file system 
but still notning.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: What kind of environment is your cluster? is your app running in a AppServer or sthg like that? The error looks like, it can not find the jar. Maybe print out the class path at the beginning of your app and check it really points at the jar.

Comment: The environment is Websphere Process server cluster with edge components.
App is running on Process server

Answer (score 0):

On the cluster at what scope did you define the JDBC driver - Cell, cluster or node - Are you sure that the class path entry for the jar is correct and that the file is there and can be "seen" by the process that WebSphere is running under.

Steve.